# How to make an 'add' function using n-1 and n+1

Tags: haskell, logic, addition

I have two functions: `n = n-1` and `n = n+1`.

How could I make an `add` function using these definitions by using recursion, if-then-else, `==`?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not show what the author has tried so far and where they got stuck.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please see the help center for advice on how to ask good questions here.

Comment: @dfeuer I believe that falls under "Too broad"...

Comment: @dfeuer [That is not a valid reason to close a question.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283177/is-too-broad-a-valid-reason-to-close-a-question-that-doesnt-show-any-research/283185#283185)

Comment: @Bakuriu "Too broad: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format". That does not apply, as you can see from the answers below.

Comment: @Boann, the people who voted to close are people who answer a lot of questions with the Haskell tag (chi has a gold badge, I have silver, and all the rest have bronze). I think it's okay for different subcommunities here to enforce somewhat different standards depending on their particular needs.

Answer (score 3):

```
inc :: Int -> Int
inc n = n + 1

dec :: Int -> Int
dec n = n - 1

add :: Int -> Int -> Int
add n 0 = n
add n m = add (inc n) (dec m)
```

So you just increase one of the numbers every time you decrease the other. If you recurse you basically repeat this process until you hit some edge condition. This is when the decreased number drops to 0 (notice: works just for natural numbers, not negative integers). You could extend it to negative numbers using if-then-else and comparison with 0 (<, >).

In logic you would probably have a function `s`. Then you would axiomatize function `add` for example as:

```
add(x,y) = add(y,x)
add(x,0) = x
add(x,s(y)) = add(s(x),y)
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `inc` and `dec` are your functions:

```
add x y | y > 0     = add (inc x) (dec y)
add x y | y < 0     = add (dec x) (inc y)
add x y | otherwise = x
```

And similarly for `subtract`.